# Property {created in html element} does not exist on type 'HTMLElement'

Tags: javascript, typescript, dom

In typescript, an html element is typed with HTMLElement. But what if I add a property to that HTML element, the HTMLElement type will fail. How can I type an html element with a new property. Here is the code where I get the error:

```
function divModify():HTMLElement{
  const div:HTMLElement= document.createElement("div");
  div.id= "test";
  div.classList.add("d-flex");
  const info={text: "Hello word"}
  Object.defineProperty(div,"info",{value:info})
  console.log(div)
  console.log(div.info)
  return div
}

divModify()
```

the error:

> Property 'info' does not exist on type 'HTMLElement'.

and a playground of the code: [code playground](https://www.typescriptlang.org/play?#code/GYVwdgxgLglg9mABAExgNwLJ1cAngCgEoAuACQBUMAZAUQBsBTAWwbCgG8BYAKEUQgQBnKCnRlKtRizYBeFHAghpUAHQQATgwCGUBvWaso%20AESo0xwgG4efMypjI5x3cOPXeotGrpbBgqjDCKlrIyCbIALTAjAAeFu58AmDCiDBgwHAy7LoxUMSIxqQMdHRwiADucOrIxgC%20NogA8gBGAFYM0CrIDMBpDAAK6nAADgzqUARmADTGaRnGU%20xoWnQgDMRzcLWEDUmCcIwqpQDm%20GY7HnsHDEdwp3abF3yaUCDqSGY89dw8Zlg4BEIQA)

Comment: You don't need `const div: HTMLElement` - TypeScript already knows that `document.createElement('div')` returns a `HTMLDivElement` - you can change it to just `const div = document.createElement("div");`

Comment: "Property 'info' does not exist on type '`HTMLElement`'." - the error is correct. There is no `HTMLElement.info` property. TypeScript's flow-analysis is amazing, but unfortunately it's still not yet sophisticated enough to track properties added or removed from object instances.

Comment: So, how could I type this variable.

Comment: Why are you wanting a custom property on an element in the first place?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

While TypeScript's flow-analyzer is very impressive and allows for types to be refined, narrowed, or widened within a scope when you use <del>type-guard</del> [type predicate functions](https://www.typescriptlang.org/docs/handbook/2/narrowing.html#using-type-predicates), `typeof` and `instanceof`, TypeScript still doesn't yet track all changes to a variable's type which should otherwise be inferable from use of the `in` operator or `Object.defineProperty`.

<sub>(UPDATE: So [TypeScript 4+ *does* use `in` for narrowing](https://www.typescriptlang.org/docs/handbook/2/narrowing.html#the-in-operator-narrowing), but only to discriminate between possibilities in union types)</sub>

...[so until TypeScript supports following `Object.defineProperty`](https://github.com/microsoft/TypeScript/issues/41424) you can workaround that limitation with some manual tweaks:

- Manually defining a new `type` that combines the DOM's built-in `HTMLDivElement` type with a singular `info: { readonly text: string }` type.

  - My code below also defines `info`'s Type as `type MyInfo` instead of being anonymous.
  - I call this `HTMLDivElementWithInfo`.
- Change the `divModify` function to return `HTMLDivElementWithInfo` instead of `HTMLDivElement`.
- Add a type-assertion to `Object.defineProperty`'s return-value (which is an alias of `div`) named `div2` as `HTMLDivElementWithInfo`.
- After all that, `tsc` will now allow you to dereference `div.info`.

Like so:

[Playground link](https://www.typescriptlang.org/play?#code/LAKALgngDgpgBAWQgSQHYDMD2cC8cDecATjAIYAmmqANhHGDAB5gBccAzmEQJaoDmAbjgBfAaEiw4ACQAqCADIARbgDcAotRgBbGKjAB1bmAAWaLLmlylqjdt1g4AMgJxeWNkjPZRoUOgCuqADGYNxUcEEkpAzKKoYmXgAUAJRssgqxtjp68aYY2PigcBFUnHDkqhaUQf7ZYAB0kWQMWfaJAEQVKu3JYiDFXfXc5BbtDJztfQOqjdSk7Ozy3Jz1FOQd5AC06JqMPVMlqGW8Rtyk1F4ACkSYUABq5-7weIQMzGztUjDU1NgA7pgiOR2iIDkFSg4ugAmCwAeQARgArGAherkGDoXgwa63GBESCJcqqAA0cHabkw7VJhBUjxgbBOoXOVxu9zpIjgyTg80sGRsmjquS8YNKmE09V%20fEJ0M5IqOYpgEswUqJKihQ3ynKKxBgYH8RFQqqhfWEvhATWiMFiQvyKSAA).

```js
type MyInfo                 = { readonly text: string; };
type HTMLDivElementWithInfo = HTMLDivElement & { info: MyInfo };

function createDivWithInfo(): HTMLDivElementWithInfo {

  const div = document.createElement("div");
  div.id = "test";
  div.classList.add("d-flex");

  const initialInfoPropValue = { text: "Hello word" };
  const div2 = Object.defineProperty( div, "info", { value: initialInfoPropValue } ) as HTMLDivElementWithInfo;

  console.log( div2 );
  console.log( div2.info );
  return div2;
}

const d = createDivWithInfo();
console.log( d.info );
```